# A circle of finite radius with points $(-2,-2),(1,4),$ and $(k,2006)$ can exist for

Tags: geometry, circles

A circle of finite radius with points $(-2,-2),(1,4),$ and $(k,2006)$ can exist for 
$(A)$ no value of $k$
$(B)$exactly one value of $k$
$(C)$exactly two values of $k$
$(D)$infinite values of $k$

---

Let $(a,b)$ be the center of the circle.
As the three points are on the circumference of the circle.
Then $(a+2)^2+(b+2)^2=(a-1)^2+(b-4)^2=(k-a)^2+(2006-b)^2$
I am stuck here.

Comment: What is a circle with infinite radius?

Comment: Try sketching the points $(-2,-2)$, $(1,4)$ and the different types of circles that include them. It might be clear then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given three arbitrary non-collinear points on a plane, we can always find **one and only one** circle whose circumference passes through them. So the answer is  $(D)$ infinite values of $k$.

Actually, the only value of $k$ for which no such circle exists, is the one making the points collinear, i.e. 
$$\frac{4-(-2)}{1-(-2)}=\frac{2006-4}{k-1}\Leftrightarrow k=1002$$

**P.S.:** Given the coplanar but non-collinear points $A,B,C$, we can determine the center of the unique circle coming through them as the point of intersection between the perpendicular bisectors of the line segments $AB$ and $BC$.